# Differential equations with coupled derivatives in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy, enthought

I am trying to solve a set of differential equations using sympy and scipy, but cannot figure out how to bring them in the appropriate form. In brief, I have a set of two coupled second order differential equations that I can re-write into a system of four first order differential equations of the form:

dot(x1) = x2

dot(x2) = f(x1, x2, x3, x4, dot(x4))

dot(x3) = x4

dot(x4) = f(x1, x2, x3, x4, dot(x2))

My problem is the coupling of the first derivatives. In Matlab, I can use a time- and state-variable dependent mass matrix to solve this, but in python, I have only seen approaches with a time-invariant mass matrix. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: It depends on what "f" is but is it possible to solve this system algebraically for `dot(x1), dot(x2), ...`?

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of essential information.  Also, as you write you're *"using sympy and scipy"*, please note that they don't work together. Sympy searches symbolic solutions and doesn't understand numpy's and scipy's functions. Scipy looks for numeric solutions, and doesn't understand about sympy symbols nor functions.  It is very tricky to combine both.